# MapReduce: Why Can't I do a Secondary Sort like this (Hadoop)?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I've implemented a Secondary Sort using the correct method: composite key, composite key comparator class, natural key grouping comparator class, and natural key partitioner class.

However, before I learned that this was necessary, I did the following:

```
class CompositeKey extends WritableComparable<CompositeKey> {
    String name; // Natural Key
    Date time;   // Secondary Sort on this value

    // Constructor

    public void readFields(DataInput in) { ... }
    public void readFields(DataInput out) { ... }
    public int compareTo(CompositeKey compositeKey) { 
        int result = getName().compareTo(compositeKey.getName());
        if (result == 0) {
            result = getTime().compareTo(compositeKey.getTime());
        }
        return result
    }

    public boolean equals(Object compositeKey) {
        // Similar code to compareTo()
    }


}
```

I figured the Mapper would emit values grouped together by the CompositeKey, whose equality would be determined by either the compareTo or the equals method.

Why doesn't this method work?

Given that most of the time the class of the Key emitted by the Mapper is the ..[hadoop.io.Text](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html) class, how does MapReduce go about figuring that member variable `bytes` is that which needs to be compared in order to group values? Why couldn't more advanced logic be utilized for the secondary sort like in my class above?

Edit I just noticed this in the source code for ..hadoop.io.Text:

```
350      /** A WritableComparator optimized for Text keys. */
351      public static class Comparator extends WritableComparator {
352        public Comparator() {
353          super(Text.class);
354        }
355    
356        @Override
357        public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1,
358                           byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
359          int n1 = WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b1[s1]);
360          int n2 = WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b2[s2]);
361          return compareBytes(b1, s1+n1, l1-n1, b2, s2+n2, l2-n2);
362        }
363      }
364    
365      static {
366        // register this comparator
367        WritableComparator.define(Text.class, new Comparator());
368      }
```

I'm assuming that if I put this in, it still wouldn't work (Given that everyone recommends doing the method listed above for secondary sorts). Why not?

Answer (score 0):

Typically a secondary sort is used when you want your values to be sorted by your secondary key and grouped by your primary key. Just using a composite key only allows you to group by both the primary and secondary keys; it does nothing for getting your values in any sorted order once it gets to the respective reducers.

Specifically: With "Name" being the primary key and "Time" being the secondary key,

Using secondary sort: Each reducer gets all the values corresponding to one "Name", and gets each data point for "Time" in sorted order, e.g., Name:Bob, Time:1,2,3,...

Using just a composite key: Each reducer gets all the values corresponding to each "Name","Time" pair. There is no guarantee that the same reducer will all the name,time pairs corresponding to the same name, hence there is no guarantee that the values for Bob are processed in Time order.

Comment: What I am not grasping is why would each reducer get all the values corresponding to each "Name","Time" pair, instead of each "Name", given that I have wrote `equals`, `compare`, or `compareto` methods? If the Sort/Reduce phases don't use any of these methods to decide "Name,"Time", by which mechanism does it decide to use "Name","Time"?

Comment: That would be the mapper output key / reducer input key. It's defined in the JobConf, e.g., http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setMapOutputKeyClass%28java.lang.Class%29

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by changing type of `name` to hadoop's `Text`. This helped me.